# Н или НН в слове «раненый»?

Tags: орфография, нн

Подскажите, как правильно? Не могу разобраться с Н в слове "раненый".
*Российский генерал, смертельно **раненый** в Бородинском сражении.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Российский генерал, смертельно **раненный** в Бородинском сражении.*

Раненный – это причастие при наличии **зависимых слов**, поэтому пишутся две буквы НН. Причастие обозначает признак **по действию**.

Сравнить: раненые солдаты, это прилагательное, без зависимых слов обозначает **качественный** признак.